# postgresql could not create a ipv6 socket: permission denied

Tags: sockets, service, ipv6, permission-denied, postgresql-9.5

How can resolve this problem? is a Ubuntu 16.04

```
Starting PostgreSQL 9.5 database server 
The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output: 
17-02-02 21:06:10 VET [23534-1] LOG:  could not create IPv6 socket: Permission denied 
17-02-02 21:06:10 VET [23534-2] LOG:  could not create IPv4 socket: Permission denied 
17-02-02 21:06:10 VET [23534-3] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost" 
17-02-02 21:06:10 VET [23534-4] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets 
...fail!
```

Answer (score -1):

On the Postgres servers this line needs to be removed in /etc/hosts if it exists:
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

Also as mentioned here if * happens to include problematic IPv6 addresses, you may solve the problem by being selective in listen_addresses (which is good practice anyway):

https://serverfault.com/questions/523687/could-not-create-ipv6-socket-postgresql-standby-error